# How to get information of public posts with Graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I think it should be possible to fetch data of public posts via Graph API or FQL.
However, when I try to get information about a public post with Graph API like:

https://graph.facebook.com/539466812_10150451924016813?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX

it just returns **false**.  This post is public and accessible via:

https://www.facebook.com/539466812/posts/10150451924016813

so I think it should be accessible by Graph API.
How should I access to the post with Graph API or FQL?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to this post
(http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5181656/help-on-facebook-graph-api-returns-false-but-uid-is-public),
it was once possible to access public posts via:

https://graph.facebook.com/(owner_id)_(postid)

before.  Has Facebook changed anything about this feature?